# add Seaborn Scatter plot to tkinter gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, plot, seaborn

I want to add this scatter plot to my tkinter gui. I ran this on my jupyter notebook and it works but I am not sure how to implement it to the tkinter gui.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvZ8v.png)

this is the window the graph should be
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO6Tt.png)

**this is the code I have on my jupyter notebook:**

```
### Import libraries
import seaborn as sns 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

import pandas as pd 

### Import dataset
players_df = pd.read_csv("player_locations.txt") 
players_df 


### Draw Seaborn Scatter Plot to find location between lat and long

sns.scatterplot(x = players_df["longitude"], y = players_df["latitude"], hue = players_df["Player"])
```

**this is the code on my gui for the analysis window:**

```
from tkinter import *

import matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

import csv

import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns

from matplotlib import animation

from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

from matplotlib import style


players_df = pd.read_csv("player_locations.txt") 
players_df

class addAnalysis(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("650x650+620+200")
        self.title("Analysis")
        self.resizable(False,False)
        
        
         #Frames
        self.top=Frame(self,height=150,bg='white')
        self.top.pack(fill=X)
        self.bottomFrame=Frame(self,height=500,bg='#f1dead')
        self.bottomFrame.pack(fill=X)
        
        #heading
        self.heading = Label(self.top, text='Player Analysis', font='arial 25 bold',
                             fg='#000000', bg='white')
        self.heading.place(x=230, y=60)
        
        
        #buttons
        graph_button = Button(self.bottomFrame,text='   Graph  ',
                      font='arial 14 bold',command = self.plot)
        graph_button.place(x=10,y=380)



        exit_button = Button(self.bottomFrame,text='    Exit     ',
                          font='arial 14 bold',command = self.destroy)
        exit_button.place(x=10,y=440)
        
#         this is the part where I implement the scatter plot
    def plot():
         # Draw Seaborn Scatter Plot to find location between lat and long
         scatter = self.sns.scatterplot(x = players_df["longitude"], y = players_df["latitude"], hue = players_df["Player"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned that tk can import PIL images. I needed to convert an numpy array with raw RGB data to tk and the advice was to use PIL.fromarray() to create a PIL image, then use ImageTk.PhotoImage() to import the PIL image into tk. I hope this information is useful to you.

Comment: I am extracting data so the points will always be changing so an image seems like something that will not be suitable for this situation

Comment: Yes, you will need to recreate the image from the data every time a data element changes.

Comment: Is there another way you can think of were I will not have create an image each time?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The only way I can think of is if you add a frame buffer in which you can edit the pixels. But the image will have to be sent the screen every few milliseconds (if you want real-time updates), and that also means converting the whole image to  a format that can be shown by tk or other GUI module. As far as I know( I am in no way an expert, I started with python about 5 months ago)